# Interact with Apps installed on Android Emulator

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Is there a way to interact with applications installed on my Android emulator. For instance I want to start WhatsApp and send messages to selected contacts, all from outside the emulator. What should I look for? Can monkeyrunner help with this case?